# Firebase structure duplication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm new with Firebase and NoSQL, I made a structure for my application and I have some questions.

My stucture :

```
 ROOT
 |
 +-- USERS
 |     |
 |     +-- USER_ID
 |           |
 |           +-- USERNAME
 |           |
 |           +-- DISPLAY_NAME
 |           |
 |           +-- PROFILE_PICTURE_URL
 |           |
 |           +-- POST_COUNT
 |
 +-- CATEGORIES
 |     |
 |     +-- CATEGORY_ID
 |           |
 |           +-- NAME
 |           |
 |           +-- POST_COUNT
 |
 +-- POSTS
 |     |
 |     +-- POST_ID
 |           |
 |           +-- MESSAGE
 |           |
 |           +-- USER_ID
 |           |
 |           +-- USERNAME
 |           |
 |           +-- DISPLAY_NAME
 |           |
 |           +-- PROFILE_PICTURE_URL
 |           |
 |           +-- CATEGORIES
 |           |     |
 |           |     +-- CATEGORY_ID
 |           |
 |           +-- LIKE_COUNT
 |
 +-- USERS_POSTS
 |     |
 |     +-- USER_ID
 |           |
 |           +-- POST_ID
 |                 |
 |                 +-- MESSAGE
 |                 |
 |                 +-- USER_ID
 |                 |
 |                 +-- USERNAME
 |                 |
 |                 +-- DISPLAY_NAME
 |                 |
 |                 +-- PROFILE_PICTURE_URL
 |                 |
 |                 +-- CATEGORIES
 |                 |     |
 |                 |     +-- CATEGORY_ID
 |                 |
 |                 +-- LIKE_COUNT
 |
 +-- CATEGORIES_POSTS
 |     |
 |     +-- CATEGORY_ID
 |           |
 |           +-- POST_ID
 |                 |
 |                 +-- MESSAGE
 |                 |
 |                 +-- USER_ID
 |                 |
 |                 +-- USERNAME
 |                 |
 |                 +-- DISPLAY_NAME
 |                 |
 |                 +-- PROFILE_PICTURE_URL
 |                 |
 |                 +-- CATEGORIES
 |                 |     |
 |                 |     +-- CATEGORY_ID
 |                 |
 |                 +-- LIKE_COUNT
 |
```

**I ask myself if these things are good or not ?**

- The posts are duplicated many times.
- The user information is present in each post, maybe I just need the user id and request the user information later ?
- Should I extract the "likeCount" in an other object ?
- When I want to update a user or a post (Or "likeCount") I have many updates to do.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a tad vague but here's some thoughts

> The posts are duplicated many times.

There's nothing wrong with duplicate data in NoSQL - it's actually quite common. However, the duplicate data needs to be for a reason, usually to assist with queries. Don't duplicate just to denormalize data for no reason other than flattening it. In the question, the duplicate data is not needed - that could change depending on what you want to do with that data.

> The user information is present in each post, maybe I just need the
>   user id and request the user information later ?

Correct! In this case duplicate data is probably not needed. Just a uid in the post will enable you to gather the rest of the user data when needed

> Should I extract the "likeCount" in an other object ?

That depends. Having a single count makes it easy to get the number of likes but doesn't link back to who liked it, so you loose that connection. On the other hand you could just store a node with uid's who liked the post. That would be very fast to count through and maintain who liked it.

> When I want to update a user or a post (Or "likeCount") I have many
>   updates to do.

Not really. If the like count is stored only in one place (with the post) that's just incrementing one node. Updating the post count in the user node, not to big of a deal either.

In general, when you are wanting to 'count' things in Firebase you can either a) read in all the nodes and count them in code or b) keep an counter node somewhere and increment on the fly. The counter node is usually the way to do so you're headed in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! About the user duplicated data in each post, you said "In this case duplicate data is probably not needed" but if I want to display the user with the post (Like facebook or twitter for example), should I request the user data after the post data or duplicate ?

Comment: @Pipiks I would suggest loading the post data for each post, which would contain the user id, and then the load user data. Since you have the uid, you can directly access the user via an observeSingleEvent (Swift) at /users/uid which avoids performing a query which is more resource intensive operation than an observe.